# Full text indexing on large files (more than 32k)

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is it possible to use Azure Search on blobs over 32kB size? I have around 500GB of text files stored as blobs on Azure. Average blob size is around 1MB. I was so exited to try Azure Search to have full text search on files. However, it looks like index field Edm.String cannot be more than 32kB. I couldn't find this exact limit anywhere, I extracted this information from error message in the portal.

Is there any out of the box solution on Azure that I can use to add full text search functionality on Blobs? Does Azure team plan to remove 32kB field size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two different limits are potentially relevant here:

1. Azure Search has a limit on how many characters it will extract from a blob, depending on the pricing tier. For free tier, that limit is 32*1024 characters. For the Standard S1 and S2 pricing tiers, it's 4 million characters.
2. Separately, there's a limit on the size of a single term in the search index - it also happens to be 32KB. If the `content` field in your search index is marked as `filterable`, `facetable` or `sortable` then you'll hit this limit (regardless of whether the field is marked as `searchable` or not). Typically for large searchable content you want to enable `searchable` and sometimes `retrievable` but not the rest. That way you won't hit limits on content length from the index side.

We realize that the first limit especially isn't documented now; we'll reflect this in our Quotas and Limits page soon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eugene. I'll definitely try S1 today. Does character limit assumes ASCII or UTF-8 characters? Does blob's content type affect character limit? As well do you have documentation how to make `content` searchable? Because I think at this moment file is extracted to `content` field (this is where I see limit error).

Comment: The limit refers to characters we extract, which are always UTF-8. Blob's content type doesn't affect this limit. To make `content` field searchable, just mark it as searchable when you create the index, either in UI or programmatically.

Comment: It should be noted that the limits have increased  for S2 and S3 tiers.  See the [table in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#indexer-limits)  and the row starting with text "Blob indexer: maximum characters of content extracted from a blob"