# "Content" too large when indexing blob content for Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I set up blob indexing and full-text searching for Azure as described in this article: [Indexing Documents in Azure Blob Storage with Azure Search](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage/).

Some of my documents are failing in the indexer, throwing the returning the following error:

> Field 'content' contains a term that is too large to process. The max length for UTF-8 encoded terms is 32766 bytes. The most likely cause of this error is that filtering, sorting, and/or faceting are enabled on this field, which causes the entire field value to be indexed as a single term. Please avoid the use of these options for large fields.

The particular pdf that is producing this error is 3.68 MB, and contains a variety of content (text, tables, images, etc).

The index and indexer are set up exactly as described in that article, with the addition of some file type restrictions.

**Index:**

```
{
    "name": "my-index",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "id",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "key": true,
        "searchable": false
    }, {
        "name": "content",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true
    }]
}
```

**Indexer:**

```
{
    "name": "my-indexer",
    "dataSourceName": "my-data-source",
    "targetIndexName": "my-index",
    "schedule": { 
        "interval": "PT2H"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "maxFailedItems": 10,
        "configuration": {
            "indexedFileNameExtensions": ".pdf,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.ppt,.pptx,.html,.xml,.eml,.msg,.txt,.text"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried searching through their docs and some other related articles, but I couldn't really find any information. I'm guessing this is because this feature is still in preview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there's a limit on the size of a single term in the search index - it also happens to be 32KB. If the `content` field in your search index is marked as `filterable`, `facetable` or `sortable` then you'll hit this limit (regardless of whether the field is marked as searchable or not). Typically for large searchable content you want to enable `searchable` and sometimes `retrievable` but not the rest. That way you won't hit limits on content length from the index side.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149382/full-text-indexing-on-large-files-more-than-32k/37150145#37150145) for more context as well.

Comment: Makes sense. So the field is marked `filterable`, `facetable`, and/or `sortable` by default?

Comment: Yes, string fields are sortable / filterable / sortable by default - see [Create Index API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798941.aspx) for all the details.

Comment: We should probably update our sample index in the blob indexing article to make all those properties as false.